# How to get maximum value of some property from all records in realm table?

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

Tried this but it doesn't work:

```
int maxValue = realm.All<myTable>().Max<myTable>().intProperty;
```

I'm getting error message:

> System.NotSupportedException: The method 'Max' is not supported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In LINQ you need to supply an expression selecting the property to [`Max()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549271(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
int maxValue = realm.All<myTable>().Max(item => item.intProperty);
```

This may not work in LINQ 2 Entity, so use

```
int maxValue = realm
    .All<myTable>()
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.intProperty)
    .First().intProperty;
```